# CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE: caffe installation

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

I had already installed `Cuda 7.5` and now I have installed `Cuda 8.0`. The Nvidia card is `TITAN X (Pascal). I also only activated the following compute abilities`CUDA_ARCH`field in`makefile.config` (the rest are commented):

```
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
-gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61
```

I successfully could run `make all` and `make test` for `Caffe` installation, however, when I tried to run `make runtest` after some time it is showing error:

```
F0509 11:19:15.078367 29181 math_functions.cu:416] Check failed: status == CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS (201 vs. 0)  CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE
```

When I type 
`ldd ./build/tools/caffe | grep cuda`, I get

`libcudart.so.7.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5 (0x00007fd3ea210000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007fd3c9f3c000)`

How to remove *.so of cuda7? or what is possible solution?Thanks

Comment: Seems like this question is for [another site](https://superuser.com/) in StackExchange.

Comment: @Inman Thanks for your comment, I could solve the issue

Comment: See https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe/issues/270

Comment: @LukeYeager Thanks for your help. I could solve it by uninstalling and reinstalling cuda toolkit as I have brought here as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by uninstalling Nvidia cuda toolkit. I followed the command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one) . 
I reinstalled cuda 8.0 and added the following paths to `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```